# Nodal analysis in circuit contain voltage controlled voltage source

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

I have a circuit below and I need to determine the potential at \$v_1\$ and \$v_2\$. I have 3 questions:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5oFLH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. How do I use nodal analysis at \$v_2\$, or how do I solve this without nodal analysis?
2. I have tried to do this:

At node \$v_1\$: \$-1+\frac{v_1-v_2}{10}+\frac{v_1}{5}+\frac{v_1-v_2}{15}=0\$

At node \$v_2\$: \$v_2 = 2v_x = 2\frac{v_2-v_1}{10} = \frac{v_2-v_1}{5}\$

$$=> \frac{11}{30}v_1-\frac{1}{6}v_2=1; \frac{1}{5}v_1+\frac{4}{5}v_2=0$$

$$=> v_1=\frac{120}{49}V; v_2=-\frac{30}{49}V$$

This is wrong, but when I ran a simulator and I accidentally set the function in VCVS is \$0.2(v_a-v_b)\$, then I have the same result. Why does this happen?

3. (This question is unrelate to 2 questions above, but just for curious) When I tried to substitute the \$I_2\$ source with a voltage source in a simulator, the simulation stop immediately, but this does not happen with \$I_1\$ source. Why does this happen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Asking about simulators and nodal analysis in one question is a step too far.

Comment: Is **a** and **b** and **v1** all connected together, as it looks they are to me?

Comment: @jonk **a** and **b** are on 2 side of the 10 ohm resistor.

Comment: I see a lot of dotted connections in your schematic. Way too many, to my eye.

Comment: @jonk sorry, this is my first time using circuit lab, let me edit the schematic.

Comment: How do you know that your result is wrong? What is the correct result? Is this coursework?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I ran a simulator to check the result. Result is v1 = 30, v2 = 60.

Comment: This is one of the problems where you think about it for 10 minutes then write your answer on a postage stamp. You have to get past the red herrings: the 10 and 15 ohm resistors are in parallel, 6 ohms. The VCVS generates V2, so V2 = 2V1. Now there's only one variable. The current through the 6 ohm parallel combination is V1/6 so the current  through the 5 ohm resistor is 1 + V1/6. At this point start writing on that postage stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that \$v_x = \frac{v_2 - v_1}{10}\$

The left-hand side is a **voltage**, the right-hand side is a **current**.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. How about question #3?